# Why is my website is getting redirected from search engine results?

Tags: website, malware, search-engines, hosting, godaddy

I have a website hosted on GoDaddy. The issue is, when I search for it on Google or Yahoo the result corresponding to the website has the right URL and description displayed, but when I click on that link, it takes me to some other website. Note that the title of my website is also displayed wrongly by search engines.

- This is on multiple search engines.
- This is not from just my computer but on all computers.

What is the issue here?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess?  Your website has been hijacked or you are not reading the search results correclty.  if you believe your website coudl have been hijacked, nuke it from orbit, and restore the files from a clean backup.

Comment: If you enter the URL into your address bar, does it work?

Comment: Can you add some screen shots?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yes it work properly then.

Comment: @learner Did you look very, **very** carefully at the URL on the search engine and ensure it is *precisely* the same as the one you are testing? Make sure you get `http` versus `https` right and `www.example.com` versus `example.com` right.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, there is no `http` or `https` in the search result URL and I don't type in `http` or `https` when I visit the site manually. There is `www` in the search result URL though. I don't usually type `www` when I visit the website manually. Does it matter though? **Another important note:** when I copied the search result URL into the browser, it took me to the right website, **but** in the status bar, I could see the name of the spam website at some point. Any way I could investigate this?

Comment: @learner If you don't understand those details or whether they matter, you're going to have a hard time tracking this down. The answer is yes, all those details matter. Most likely, it has nothing to do with the search engines -- they're just finding some URL that goes to some other web site hosted by GoDaddy on the same machine as your site.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the source code of your website and if you find any weird changes in your source code rectify it and then check it once again.Also change the password to your Godaddy account ,maybe someone's trying to use your account to get visits to their sites.So changing the password of your account might help!!